# Cache no Segundo Nível - JPA e EclipseLink

Tags: jpa, eclipse-link

Gostaria de desabilitar, de forma total, a cache do JPA/EclipseLink, mas não estou conseguindo.

Consigo desabilitar a cache em primeiro nível usando:

```
query.setHint("javax.persistence.cache.storeMode", CacheStoreMode.REFRESH)
```

Mas a cache em segundo nível não é desabilitada.

O que devo fazer para que as subtabelas (@ManyToOne) sejam buscadas diretamente do BD sem uso de cache?

**Persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="br.com.empresa_Sistema_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/sistema</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.refresh" value="true"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Experimentou utilizar `@Cacheable(false)`?

Comment: Seria bom também dar uma olhada na [documetação](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Development/JPA_2.0/cache_usaged).

Comment: @FelipeSoares, adicionei `@Cacheable(false)` na classe da entidade principal e da secundária, mas não funcionou. Continua mostrando atualizadas apenas as informações da entidade principal, a secundária atualiza no BD, mas nas consultas aparece inalterada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema estava na declaração do `EntityManager` usado para pegar os itens das consultas:

```
private static final EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("br.com.empresa_Sistema_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU").createEntityManager();
```

Passei a usar o `EntityManager` do `Facade` da entidade e a cache passou a não ser mais utilizada, prevalecendo as configurações do arquivo `Persistence.xml`, listado acima.

**Facade**

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "br.com.empresa_Sistema_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU")
protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

public EntityManager getEM() {
    return getEntityManager();
}
```

Inclusive não precisei mais utilizar o `setHint()` para configurar a `CacheStoreMode`, que no `EM` anterior funcionava apenas para desabilitar a cache da entidade principal, não funcionando para as entidades de segundo nível.